# Can we use the YouTube api_key directly for production ready softwares?

Tags: google-api, youtube

I am building a small project where I am using YouTube's API since I am using its search feature to search for a few specific videos. So for this project, can I use the API key I created and push the code to the public (obv hiding the API key) or should I be using OAuth to authenticate and use YouTube search through that?

If I choose the second option, how do I get the credentials after a certain user signs in with Google? Thanks a lot for you help!